Python, Kivy and KivMob - not showing test AdMob ads
I have a simple code using test IDS for AdMob. It uses test add and app IDs to run a test banner code. I have successfully compiled and uploaded it. But, nothing happens - no ads, whatsoever.
What am I doing wrong? Code:

Banner Ad Test Program

`
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivmob import KivMob, TestIds


class AdApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.kivmob = KivMob("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713")  # Test App ID
        self.kivmob.new_banner("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111")  # Test Banner ID
        self.kivmob.request_banner()

        layout = BoxLayout(orientation='horizontal')
        exit_button = Button(text='Exit', size_hint=(0.1, 0.1))
        exit_button.bind(on_press=self.exit_app)

        layout.add_widget(exit_button)
        return layout

    def exit_app(self, instance):
        App.get_running_app().stop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    AdApp().run()`



Simple code
Display AdMob test banner
On click of button, exit program

Tried on various phones (both old and new). No ads show.

I have successfully compiled and uploaded - uploaded to where. Are you running on emulator (OS version) or device (make/model/OS version) and installed from where Google Play Store or side-loaded from PC. What if anything does the logcat say.

@MorrisonChang : thanks for taking the time.
Answer:

I have successfully compiled and uploaded - uploaded to where: compiled using Colab. Installed on Android phones.
Are you running on emulator (OS version): No.
Device (make/model/OS version): Android 14 and Android 8
Installed from where Google Play Store or side-loaded from PC: APK file uploaded to Drive and installed from there.
What if anything does the logcat say: no errors, successful run.
That is why I am baffled.
Thank you!


This the way you can use kivmob .
https://github.com/Sahil-pixel/Youtube-Kivy-Kivymd/tree/main/ADMOB_KIVY_UPDATED

SK SAHIL - I had seen your YouTube videos and was skeptical about this code.
But, it was italic perfect_italic_! Thank you! This explains A LOT!
Thank you VERY much!
